# The current Model no longer mathces the modes used to pre-generate the mapping views

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I am trying to access a table in a database using EF 6.1.0 But I am getting an error when I try get the data from one particular table in the database. I imported the database from an already existing database with a ado.net item.

Here is the code where I get an error:

```
var dbSrc = new WebInterfaceOldEntities();
List<ut_User> users = dbSrc.ut_User.ToList();    <=====  error
```

Here is the error im getting:

```
The current model no longer matches the model used to pre-generate the mapping views, as indicated by the ViewsForBaseEntitySets879d00ec20bbbe0601fa7418ff0a96685f5823797e74e2cf3e6f22fdb0b43cc9.MappingHashValue property. Pre-generated mapping views must be either regenerated using the current model or removed if mapping views generated at runtime should be used instead. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=318050 for more information on Entity Framework mapping views.
```

And here is my Ut_User Class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace FillkDb
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class ut_User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AccessLevel { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Creator { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string PhoneWork { get; set; }
        public string PhoneHome { get; set; }
        public string Cell { get; set; }
        public string AddressStreet1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressStreet2 { get; set; }
        public string AddressStreet3 { get; set; }
        public string AddressPostCode { get; set; }
        public System.Guid msrepl_tran_version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the context:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class WebInterfaceOldEntities : DbContext
{
    public WebInterfaceOldEntities()
        : base("name=WebInterfaceOldEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }    

    public virtual DbSet<ut_User> ut_User { get; set; }
    ...   
}
```

Comment: The error is saying that the autogenerated model no longer matches the db schema - has the db or model changed since it was generated?

Comment: it says that yes, but it says that immediately after I import the database. So there have definatly been no changes to it.